# AngularJS - Json em LocalStorage não atualiza Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, array, localstorage

Tenho um formulário em uma View que deveria atualizar a propriedade "color" de um Array. Este Array `colors` possui 5 objetos, cada um servindo para definir a cor de um elemento de uma outra View (por isso a opção de usar localStorage, já que não posso usar nenhum acesso ao servidor, como $http).

A view do form (settings.html)

```
  <form name="colorform" class="row col-md-offset-1" ng-submit="update(key)">
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
              <label>Color A (Tiles)</label>
              <input name="main" ng-model="colors[0].color" class="form-control">    
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label>Color B (Blocked Tiles)</label>
              <input name="locker" ng-model="colors[1].color" class="form-control">    
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label>Color C (Path)</label>
              <input name="path" ng-model="colors[2].color" class="form-control">    
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label>Color D (Start Point)</label>
              <input name="path" ng-model="colors[3].color" class="form-control">    
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label>Color E (End Point)</label>
              <input name="path" ng-model="colors[4].color" class="form-control">    
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
              Update
          </button>
          <a href="#/" class="btn btn-primary">Back</a>
          <hr>
      </div>
  </form>
```

Trecho do BoardController.js (que deveria guardar a atualização no localStorage e atualizar o Array colors em seguida):

```
//Array a ser atualizado
$scope.colors = [
    {name: "main", color: "white"},
    {name: "locker", color: "black"},
    {name: "path", color: "yellow"}, 
    {name: "start", color: "green"},
    {name: "end", color: "blue"},
];

//localStorage

$scope.update = function (key) {
    localStorage.setItem( 'colors', angular.toJson( $scope.colors, '[]' ) );
    console.log(JSON);

    var newColors = angular.fromJson( localStorage.getItem( 'colors' ) );
    for (var i = 0; i < newColors.length; i++) {
        $scope.colors == $scope.colors;
        $scope.colors = newColors[i];

        console.log($scope.colors);
    }
}
/*função que aplica o estilo nos elementos da view main.html
  Necessita utilizar $scope.status[$index] pois os índices do Array
  são os mesmos da variável status (não exibida neste código), que define
  o estado de cada elemento
*/
$scope.style = function ($index) {       
    return {
        "height" : tileHeight + 'px',
        "width" : tileWidth + 'px',
        "border" : "1px solid #CCC",
        "background-color": $scope.colors[$scope.status[$index]].color,
        "float": "left"
    }
}
```

E em main.html, a utilização do style:

```
<!-- Através do ng-style -->
<div ng-repeat="tile in getNumber(tiles) track by $index" 
     ng-click="changeToggle($index)" ng-init="initToggle($index)" 
     ng-model="status[$index]" ng-style="style($index)"></div>
</div>
```

Os dados estão sendo armazenados corretamente, como mostra a imagem do localStorage abaixo (reparem que o primeiro registro foi atualizado para "gray" pelo form):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, não consigo fazer a localStorage atualizar o array, e consequentemente alterar as cores da View main.html. O que está errado?